# JSF get current action in managed bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, java-ee-6

When user clicks any `commandButton`, then corresponding action is called in managed bean.
Is it possible to get this action name from `@PostConstruct` method or from event listener method ?

Comment: Must be there in `request`, inspect it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The button's name=value pair is by itself available as HTTP request parameter the usual way. Imagine that the generated HTML representation of the command button look like this

```html
<input type="submit" name="formId:buttonId" value="Submit" ... />
```

Then it's present as a request parameter with name `formId:buttonId` with a non-null value. JSF uses exactly this information during the Apply Request Values phase to determine if the button was pressed or not. This happens during the `decode()` method of the renderer associated with the button component, roughly as follows:

```
if (externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().containsKey(component.getClientId(context))) {
    component.queueEvent(new ActionEvent(component));
}
```

Or when it concerns an ajax request, then the button's name is instead available as value of the `javax.faces.Source` request parameter.

```
if (component.getClientId(context).equals(externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("javax.faces.Source"))) {
    component.queueEvent(new ActionEvent(component));
}
```

Either way, the `ActionEvent` is ultimately stored as a private field of `UIViewRoot` which is in *no way* available by a public API. So, unless you grab reflection and implementation specific hacks, it's end of story here.

To determine the button pressed your best bet is to manually check the request parameter map the same way as JSF itself does.

Depending on the concrete functional requirement, which is not exactly clear from the question, an alternative may be to use `actionListener` or `<f:actionListener>` on all `UICommand` components of interest, or to use `<action-listener>` in `faces-config.xml` to register a global one. This will be invoked *right before* the real `action` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIComponent sourceComponent = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: And version info for which this works should also  be added. Might not work for older versions